# ASP.NET MVC : DropDownList to model field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dropdown

My model is a rpg character. He has a field "Game", that is a strongly types object containing "Careers" fields, themselves strongly types object.
Model must choose a career amidst multiple choices.

I currently display it as is :

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.career, 
      new SelectList(Model.game.professions, "name", "name"), 
      )
```

(where professions is of type List[career]).

However, this does not bind the selected value of the dropdownlist to the career field of my character.

Any hint? I've been searching for a while, but I only find way to populate a dropdownlist from a model, and nothing on how to ensure the selected value is passed back to the model.

Thank you

Edit = I accepted RedGoodBreaker's answer even though it wasn't what I expected because it helped me find the solution.

Point is : you can't select an object via DDL in mvc, you can only select a basic type that references to that object (in my case, I chose the string field "name" of my career).

Comment: Is model.career a complex object or just an id (int) or name (string)

Comment: @RedgoodBreaker It's a complex object with no ID, as it's entirely created inside "game". It consists of a string "name" and a list of skills jobSkills

Comment: MVC can't determine value from your complex type and set it to control, i would recommend either to add new property as string which will act as helper to get and set value on form. OR create Custom Html Helper which will take your complex type and populate a dropdown accordingly. Let me know if you need code for custom helper

Comment: @KD But how can MVC determine the content of my model when it must display it (as the name of each profession is clearly shown in my page), but not when it must bind the value to the model's field? ._. (I would like your code for the custom helper, I've done a few myself but it never hurts to see someone else's way of doing things )

Comment: Html does not have any possibility to "bind". Defalut Html `DropDown` can have simple `Value` and simple `Text`. HTML does not understand "objects". If you want something like this. you should make some javascript code on event onChange wchich will populate hidden fields. I don't know what do you want display or if you want post it back to server. write some more code how view should look after selecting value and what you are expecting to have on server side after submiting form

Comment: I display a dropdownlist to allow user to choose one of the careers by name. I managed to do that with the code in the post.

The dropdown is included in a traditionnal editpage with many other inputs for the various fields of my model, as either displayfor or textboxfor extension methods.

On click on the save button, my character model is updated with the values of the form for each fields, except for his "career" field, which value is set to "null" despite having a drop down list.

I want the value selected in the drop down list to become the value of the character's field "career".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.DropDownListFor` generates html like

```
<select id="CarType" name="CarType">
  <option value="a">Volvo</option>
  <option value="b">Saab</option>
  <option value="c">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="d">Audi</option>
</select>
```

so as you can see they are simple strings(in your case both value and text are the same). when you select one posting form will produce something like that:

```
...
CarType="a"
...
```

You can do several tricks but question is it worth doing it and do you really need it.

Normally your model should have field `CarrerName` and dropdownlist should be bound to it. In `Controller` `Action` which accepts form submission you should rehydrate `Carrer` from database or other store using `CarrerName` (this is why we asked about id).

I understand that `Skills` are some kind of dictionary that does not change much. Options for storing are(there maybe some others that i am not aware):

1. save your dictionary to `Session` before presenting form or better after logon if this dictionary does not change. You can access it after form submission and find apropriate key (best int or guid)
2. `System.Web.Caching.Cache`.
3. `TempData`.
4. `Database`.

this options have its cons and pros about which you must read because i don't know your application specification.

If you need this data before submission in view or javascript you have to do it yourself ( there is no simple one-liner). I can help but i dont know what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Well,my character HAS a field "metier" which is of type "career". In the controller, I pass the character object submitted by the form to my repository, which does the update with the new values.

So what I don't understand is why the selected career doesn't bind to the career field of my character ^^"

Comment: wait, I can't bind an object, I must bind a simple type property? Is that it? I can't simply pass the career to my character, I HAVE TO pass a reference to the career? Is that it?

Comment: HTML does not understand what is object. Reference won't help because when you post form it is creating new instances of objects.  Web applications does not work like desktop. Every request is a new thread so you have different memory allocation. Just tell us what do you want to achieve. Do you need that "binding" only on server side or browser ?

Comment: Well the "career" object contains a list of skills (that's also a class from the project). I need to bind the career object to the Character object, so that I know which skills are to be treated.
And when I post the form, it can understand that I create a character, so why can't it use the career object as well?

I managed to pass a string field containing the name of my career when I submit the form, and added backend logic to that, but I think it's weird I have to bind a field of my subobject instead of the object itself.

Comment: again there is no such thing like object in HTML. Its possible to make it but its harder to make and creates security vulnerabilty to your site. I understand that Skills are some kind of dictionary, So if this data would be hidden in form then someone could modify this fields and send false data, which you would persist in database. Only thing you need to pass is the identification of this field in dictionary. If you have additional requirement to use some value of this dictionary value you should rehydrate it. there are several posibilities to do that if you really dont want to get if from db

Comment: 1. save your dictionary to `Session` before presenting form or better after logon if this dictionary does not change. You can access it after form submission and find apropriate key (best int or guid)
2. System.Web.Caching.Cache use it in simmilar way as `Session` but remeber itt  work in a different way.
3. there is `TempData`. 
4. get it again from DB.
this options have its cons and pros about which you must read because i don't know your application specification.

Comment: It's not a dictionary, but thanks anyway. I managed to get the dropdownlist working by passing a reference, I just think it sucks (nothing blocks the user to send a false reference more than a false object and I check backend what is sent, so it's a bit weird asp can't bind the object)

Thanks for your help to;

Answer (score 0):

Your career object should have Id field and you need to pass it to DropDownListFor

Please refer the below link

[MVC DropDownList](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Comment: but why can't I use the name field inside career object instead of the id field? (Cause I don't have an ID field and I don't really want to change both character and career models)

Comment: you can't change model, then use viewmodel

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I can change the model, I just don't see how adding an ID field model will help, since I don't have a clue where to use it or how. Hence I don't want to add it.

Answer (score 0):

and then in the Razor view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => model.career, new SelectList(Model.game.professions, "Value", "Text"), "Career")
```

Of course the model needs to be passed into the view with the values in the List already populated